# how do i store django media on remote unix server

Tags: django, rhel7

I have two app servers 10.22.33.54 and 10.22.33.56 and I am trying to integrate media on another server IP 10.22.30.40 I created a media directory so what are the method I can use in Django to manage media files?

Comment: Can you `ssh` to the remote server from the app server? If yes, you can use [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs).

Comment: no, I can't use ssh from 40 servers can I use NFS?

Comment: I don't see any reason you can't. Have you tried?

Comment: NFS is  working i implemented by help of this  link  https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/